# Xamarin iOS: Check if Google fit app is installed on the device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-fit

Is there any way to check if 'Google Fit' app is installed on iOS device?

I tried:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl("FitApp://com.google.fit"));
```

this always returns false

Comment: Did you add `FitApp:` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your info.plist?

Comment: If I add it, above code is always true, regardless of 'google fit' being installed on the device or not.

Comment: What happens when you open the URL when the app  isn't installed?  You need to specify the URL in your queries schemes key.  Another app may be responding to that URL. There is no way to detect that a specific app is installed, only to infer it by checking for a URL scheme

Comment: are you positive that's the correct URL?  I don't get any hits when I *ahem* google it

Comment: @Jason it is correct URL, if you install the googleFit app and use that url it opens the app, I am also worried that apple might ask the same question that how I got the url schema. Btw is there any other way on IOS to check if any app is installed on the phone?

Comment: @Paulw11 `CanOpenUrl` always returns false, `OpenUrl` returns true if app is installed and false if it is not. But `OpenUrl` opens the app when it is installed, I dont want to open the app, I just want to see if that app is installed on the device or not.

Comment: You should only pass the URL scheme (`FitApp:`) to `canOpenURL`, not the full URL.

Comment: @Paulw11 `CanOpenURL` returns false even for the URL scheme (`FitApp:`)

Comment: Make sure you add `FitApp` (no colon) to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array and query for `FitApp:` in `canOpenURL` - I just tested this in Swift and it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `FitApp` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array in your Info.plist (note, there is no colon).

Then, in code your can check to see if you can open `FitBit:` - note the colon

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl("FitApp:"));
```